# Error building Jasmine

Tags: rake, jasmine

I am trying to build Jasmine from

https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine

I cloned the repo

Then am trying to do

```
rake --trace
```

But am getting the following error

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- bundler
/home/pdave/jasmine/jasmine/Rakefile:1:in `require'
/home/pdave/jasmine/jasmine/Rakefile:1
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:82:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:27
```

What should I do to correct and be able to build the project.

Answer (score 0):

That is a problem with the project setup instructions. Obviously you need the bundler gem.
With ruby this is usually installed with `gem install bundler`. After that you can try to build again (hopefully this was the last dependency).